# deploying Xamarin Forms application over USB throws exception

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

Good afternoon,

I encountered the following problem in deploying from visual studio 2019 to either existing android emulator as well as a physical android device over USB

```
10-08 13:04:19.890 D/Mono    ( 3655): Assembly Ref addref SelectronMobileApp[0x77deaf1d80] -> SData[0x77deb43980]: 2
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ProcessDebugHeader()
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols(ISymbolReader reader)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.LoadPdbFile(String assemblyFileName, String pdbFileName) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2816
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.LoadDebugFile(String assemblyFileName, String debugFileName, Func`3 loadDebugFile) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2916
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.CheckBetterMatch(TypeMirror type, String file, Int32 line, Int32 column, Location found) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2943
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.FindLocationByMethod(MethodMirror method, String file, Int32 line, Int32 column, Boolean& insideTypeRange) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 3118
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.FindLocationByType(TypeMirror type, String file, Int32 line, Int32 column, Boolean& genericMethod, Boolean& insideTypeRange) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 3136
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveBreakpoints(TypeMirror type) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2629
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleTypeLoadEvents(TypeLoadEvent[] events) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 2183
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es) in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 1722
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler() in E:\A\_work\4743\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerSession.cs:line 1644
```

After this, everything stops working and I cannot get the application to run anymore. Multiple restarts of the system did not solve the problem.

I encountered the problem first time when I needed to do work in an external class library, which is also referenced as dll in the project, however, this is not the dll that is supposedly leading to this error.

Is there anyone that can provide a lead on how to solve this issue? or can provide some insight in how to continue?

edit: fixed, in an earlier attempt i unticked the option to preserve cache between sessions in the android settings menu, which changed the problem. Searching for this new issue lead to several suggestions. The one that turned out succesful was resetting android emulator to factory default. This solved the problem for the usb debugging as well

Comment: The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state. But here moreover looks to be debug point issue. can you remove/disable any debug points then restart IDE and try again.

Comment: @user8608556 Thanks for pitching in. I edited my question with my fix. But I will sure to keep your suggestion in my mind when emulator behaves unexpected again